# Login/logout use case

Tags: use-case

Suddenly I've been in need of making an use case and I've stumped over a dilemma with the login/logout.

A co-worker tells me that they should be a use case by themselves like:

```
[login, admin stuff, logout]
```

But my brain yells at me that login should be an include of the use cases that needs a login while logout should be an extend of login.

```
[admin stuff -include> login -extends> logout]
```

So, which one?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about planning software design, not about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Models are rarely right or wrong in absolute terms; they are simply more or less useful for a given purpose. Use cases are models of actions that users of your system are supposed to carry out. From your (too brief) description, I'd probably model Login and Logout as two separate, independent use cases.

Why would you extend one from the other? What is the commonality that they would share from your viewpoint?

Comment: Viewing it from the theoretical point of view and IMO, every action an authenticated user should do must have an include to login, as it is essential and necessary for the action to happen. Having it as a separated use case brings very little to the diagram and shows no correlation between a login and any other action that needs a login.

Comment: @Ben: I understand. But use case diagrams do not show that kind of dependencies between use cases. You need other kind of diagrams to capture the fact that "a user cannot perform a task without having logged in first".

Comment: @CesarGon: you seem to confuse the extend dependency with generalization. If use case B extends use case A, it means, that there is such a scenario in use case A, that use case B is part of it. If use case A generalizes  use case B, it means every scenario of use case B is a scenario in use case A. Precise semantics of use case generalization ("inheritance") are unknows - the use is mostly to provide reusable abstract use case with details specified in concrete use cases. This is tricky and use case generalization can lead to unexpected semantics, so it is best to avoid it altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Use cases are a way to describe the goals of an actor (user/other system/...), which are achieved through interaction with the system under design.

This leads most people to exclude authentication (login/logout) from use cases, because administrators don't use systems in order to login, but to administer the system.

However, I tend to argue, that it is a goal of an administrator to be identified by the system in order to prevent misuse. This is a fairly low level use case and you should decide yourself if including it provides any value.

As to the relations between use cases, it seems you are a bit confused by them. 
Admin stuff includes login means, that whenever an administrator uses the system for administration, he wants the system to log him in. This seems valid, but you should probably make a difference between 'logging in' and 'authentication' - the administrator doesn't have to log in with username and password every time he uses the system, but the system has to authenticate - validate users identity (e.g. by username and login, but afterwards using cookie). So I would be careful with naming here.
Admin stuff extends logout means, that when an administrator uses the system to logout, in some scenarios (situations) it might happen, that he would also use the system to administer stuff. This obviously makes no sense. If you turn it the other way around - logout extends the admin stuff, it would be more reasonable, yet it is for yo uto decide, if logout is really what administrators are using the system for.

Hope you now understand use cases better and that you are able to make a good decision by yourself, good luck!